# BlueImp Jquery Upload - Get index from data.files

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

How do I get the index value from the following code?

```
add: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        alert('Added file: ' + index + " -- " + file.name);
});
```

The INDEX always return (0) even though I have (3) files. The FILE.NAME works and I am able to see all (3) files.

This was the output:

- Added file: 0  --  dog.jpg
- Added file: 0  --  cat.jpg
- Added file: 0  --  honeybadger.jpg

This is what I was expecting/desired results to :

- Added file: 0  --  dog.jpg
- Added file: 1  --  cat.jpg
- Added file: 2  --  honeybadger.jpg

After some debugging, it appears that the form is submitted (3) times which is why I get (0) for each file. Also, I have copied the code from the GIT WIKI but no luck.

Hoping a BlueImp expert can help out.

**UPDATE CODE:**
The below code is now returning the each index

```
$('#fileUpload1').fileupload(
{
    replaceFileInput: false,
    dateType: 'json',
    url: 'Handlers/AjaxFileHandler.ashx',
    singleFileUploads: false,
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('#upLoadButton').click(function () {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                alert('Added file: ' + index + " -- " + file.name);

                var v = $('input[data-id=' + index + ']').val();
                var d = $('select[data-id=' + index + ']').val();
                alert('textField:' + v + '  selected: ' + d);               
            });

            data.submit();

        });
    },
});

});
```

Comment: How does data.files look like..??

Comment: Its a HTML Object>Files (input type=file): http://www.alltechtips.com/html/objects/input_file.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not correctly using the `Add` method function callback.
In fact this event is fired by default for each single file. Data representing the file not the array of files.
You need to set `singleFileUploads` to false in order to get what you want as in example below:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        previewSourceMaxFileSize: 0,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp|svg|wmv|avi|mpe?g|mp4|ppt|pps)$/i,
        global:false,
        singleFileUploads:false, //set this to false to handle multi files upload behaviour
        add:function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                alert('Added file: ' + index + " -- " + file.name);
            });
        },
        autoUpload: false
    });
```

Comment: The above code is working, however, when the upload occurs, only one file out of three is uploaded. See updated code above.